# Whats wrong with my chart about below excercise

Tags: r, plot, statistics

What is the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables with a uniform uniform distribution on the range 0 to 1? Just make the appropriate simulation, the result is presented on the graph and commented on it.

my code:

```
x<-runif(10,0,1)
y<-runif(10,0,1)
z<-x+y
plot(density(x),col='blue')
par(new = TRUE)
plot(density(y),ann=FALSE, axis = FALSE,col='green')
par(new = TRUE)
plot(density(z),ann=FALSE, axis = FALSE,col='red')
```

Comment: It's `axes` not `axis`. You should also consider what the x-axis is on each of those three plots.. Perhaps increase the sample size a lot.

Comment: Take a look at the [pdf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/density-of-sum-of-two-uniform-random-variables-0-1) of that sum.

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Problem with the result or with plotting? When simulating 1000 values, I get a nice joint normal and two uniform distributions.